# Email access null in Facebook SDK iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook

```
    - (void)facebookViewControllerDoneWasPressed:(id)sender {

NSLog(@"FACEBOOK VIEW CONTROLLER");


NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

// we pick up the users from the selection, and create a string that we use to update the text view
// at the bottom of the display; note that self.selection is a property inherited from our base class
for (id<FBGraphUser> user in self.friendPickerController.selection) {
    if ([text length]) {
        [text appendString:@", "];
    }
    [text appendString:user.name];

    //[user objectForKey:@"email"];

 //   [text appendFormat:[user objectForKey:@"email"]];


    NSLog(@"EMAIL IS %@", [user objectForKey:@"email"]);

}

   // [self fillTextBoxAndDismiss:text.length > 0 ? text : @"Email"];

[self fillTextBoxAndDismiss:text];


}
```

I want to get email address of my friends list.

I get FBGraphUser user, but it does not return me email

I tried this but it returns null.

```
           NSLog(@"EMAIL IS %@", [user objectForKey:@"email"]);
```

Here email is null, Is it possible to access the email of my friends?

Comment: That Question's answer is not clear to me. It asking to permission but where should I paste permission code.

Comment: Also it gives me error for permission, that that message does not exist. facebookSessionStateChanged

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258910/ios-facebook-sdk-getting-friends-emails